# For a HASL Finish PCB, Can Gold Plating be done

Tags: pcb-fabrication

We have a HASL finished PCB but the pads needed gold plating for wirebonding.

Can gold plating be done on top layer of PCB over this?

Will there be any reliability issues?

Comment: Ask the people who made your circuit boards. It's going to depend on their processes, not someone's opinion on the internet.

Answer (score 3):

> Can gold plating be done on top layer of PCB over this?

No.

HASL is an indiscriminate process that affects all exposed copper on the PCB.  Therefore you'd be trying to deposit gold onto a thin layer of uneven solder, which would cause all sorts of alignment problems for wirebonding.  Also the gold would simply float off molten HASL layer as soon as the (other) components were soldered down during reflow soldering.

Just have the entire PCB ENIG treated instead of HASL and then any further gold plating needed would have a solid and perfectly flat surface to bond to.

ENIG is not expensive, and is better than HASL in every way.

Comment: >ENIG is not expensive, and is better than HASL in every way. - I've been told that ENIG (while great for most applications) is not suitable for wirebonding. I believe electroless gold is suggested. But the OP should check with their fab.

Comment: ENIG is fine for Aluminium wirebonding, I assume that is what the OP would be using given the nature of this question.  For gold wires you'd probably need ENEPIG but I'm less familiar with that and I think it's probably less easily available and more expensive.